# The markers don't appear on GMAP

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google Maps Demo

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

  var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('marker' + i + 'images/13.png',
                  new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
                  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                  new google.maps.Point(10, 34));

      var location = locations[i];
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          title: location[0],
          zIndex: location[3]
      });
  }
}
</script>
```

I'm using WAMPSERVER, and I store my 13.png under images folder (www/tacking/images/13.png).  I put my .php file under www/tracking/testing.php. Did I put my path correctly?

Please guide me...

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
 var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('marker' + i + 'images/13.png'
```

You are looking for a marker at: 'marker' + i + 'images/13.png'

Which will be something like: markerNimages/13.png

Looks like that's not where you have the PNG file right? You say you have put it in images/13.png. How about you just get rid of the 'marker' + i ?

Comment: hi DasBoot.thx for replied. i have tried,but it still doesnt work..! Actually i`m going to retrieve lat,lng from my database on i`m going to plot the makers on the GMAP. After that i want all the makers path/link with each others.Do u hv any idea on doing this? if yes,pls help me, as i reli tried it for few day already. Thx in advance and god bless

Comment: @user: Do you have a different *.png file for the different markers?